# Alternate way to code this function without 're' (regular expression) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I asked my friend for assistance with a function that swaps characters in a string, and this is what he came up with:

```
import re           

def function(a, b, c):
    def hfunc(y):
        z = y.group(1).lower()
        if z == c.lower():
            return b.upper()

        if z == b.lower():
            return c.upper()

        # The statements I commented out were supposed to print out if paramters 
        # 'b' or 'c' were not present in the string ('a')
        #if b not in a:         
             #print("Cannot be found: ", b)
             #return
        #if c not in a:
             #print("Cannot be found: ", c)  
             #return
        else:
            return y.group(1)

    return re.sub("(\w+)", hfunc, a) 

print(function("Neill and Nathan left the school.", "neill", "nathan"))
print(function("Neill and Nathan left the school.", "Nathan", "neILL"))
print(function("and Bob work together.", "dylan", "bob"))
# Cannot be found: "dylan" <-- should be the output
print(function("Dylan and work together.", "DYLAN", "BoB"))
# Cannot be found: "BoB"  <-- should be the output
```

The problem is I'm not familiar at all with the module that is being used. Is there another way to write this code (perhaps a little more beginner-friendly)? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: These are the outputs right now

```
NATHAN and NEILL left the school. # correct
NATHAN and NEILL left the school. # correct
and DYLAN work together. # Cannot be found: "dylan" <-- should be the output
BOB and work together. # Cannot be found: "BoB"  <-- should be the output
```

Comment: Can you please post what the program currently outputs, as well as what you expect it to output?

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is using [the regular expression `\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/uWUeGS/1) to match all strings of "word characters". In [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), "word characters" means:

> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore.

Really, you probably don't want to include numbers and underscores, just letters. Your friend probably did this because… well, most regular expression solutions are "quick & dirty" instead of precise; it's just shorter to specify `\w` than what you actually want, and it works for your sample inputs, so that's what they did.

So, for your first example, it'll match:

```
['Neill', 'and', 'Nathan', 'left', 'the', 'school']
```

For each one, it's calling that `hfunc`, and substituting the result in place of the original word. That's what [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) does.

---

If you want to do the same thing without using `re`, you can group the words in the same way, and loop over the groups manually. For example, with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), to group characters by whether they're letters or not (without the hacky numbers-and-underscores bit):

```
for isletters, group in itertools.groupby(sentence, key=str.isalpha):
    print(isletters, list(group))
```

If you run that and look at the output, you should be able to see what to do. First, we want to `join` each group back into a string. Then, for the ones where `isletters` is true, we want to call that `hfunc` (but let's rename it, and its parameter, to something more meaningful…). Then `join` all the results back up. So:

```
def fixword(word): # was hfunc
    if word.lower() == c.lower():
        return b.upper()
    elif word.lower() == b.lower():
        return c.upper()
    else:
        return word

newsentence = []
for isletters, group in itertools.groupby(sentence, key=str.isalpha):
    word = ''.join(group)
    if isletters:
        word = fixword(word)
    newsentence.append(word)
return ''.join(newsentence)
```

If you want to keep track of whether anything was changed, you can do that, as you go along:

```
foundb, foundc = False, False

def fixword(word): # was hfunc
    nonlocal foundb, foundb
    if word.lower() == c.lower():
        foundc = True
        return b.upper()
    elif word.lower() == b.lower():
        foundb = True
        return c.upper()
    else:
        return word

newsentence = []
for isletters, group in itertools.groupby(sentence, key=str.isalpha):
    word = ''.join(group)
    if isletters:
        word = fixword(word)
        if word == 
    newsentence.append(word)
if not foundb:
    return f'Cannot be found: {b}'
elif not foundc:
    return f'Cannot be found: {c}'
else:
    return ''.join(newsentence)
```

---

If you don't understand how that `groupby` works… well, the "roughly equivalent" code in the docs probably won't help you without a bit more study, but you can easily write something less flexible that gives the same output for this case. It's probably worth trying it. Here's a pseudocode framework to get your started:

```
currentword, isletters = [], True
for ch in sentence:
    if ch.isalpha():
        if isletters:
            add the current word to newsentence
            start a new letters word
        else:
            current_word.append(ch)
    else:
        if not isletters:
            do the fixword logic above on the current word
            add that to newsentence
            start a new non-letters word
        else:
            current_word.append(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, that has only one flaw I found: It doesn't deal with punctuation correctly. If that is a problem, tell me.

```
def function(a, b, c):
    # Give error messages
    if b.lower() not in a.lower():
        print("Cannot be found:", repr(b))
    if c.lower() not in a.lower():
        print("Cannot be found:", repr(c))

    a = a.split(" ")  # separates the words along spaces
    output = []
    for word in a:
        if word.lower() == b.lower():  # is the word b?
            output.append(c)  # add c
        elif word.lower() == c.lower():  # is the word c?
            output.append(b)  # add b
        else:  # the word is neither a nor b
            output.append(word)  # leave the word unchanged
    return " ".join(output)


print(function("Neill and Nathan left the school.", "neill", "nathan"))
print(function("Neill and Nathan left the school.", "Nathan", "neILL"))
print(function("and Bob work together.", "dylan", "bob"))
print(function("Dylan and work together.", "DYLAN", "BoB"))
```